# location of elements in a panel wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to find the child elements positions in a stack panel.

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <ToggleButton Width="20"
                           Height="20"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Visibility="Visible" />
             <TextBlock Margin="5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="15"
                        Text="Selection Mode" />
         </StackPanel>
```

How to find the X,Y position of Toggle button and Text block?

Comment: @AndreasJohansson: relation to the stack panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use [TranslatePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) to translate coordinates relative to one UIElement to coordinates relative to another UIElement:

```
var toggleButtonPosition = toggleButton.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), stackPanel);
var textBlockPosition = textBlock.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), stackPanel);
```

The above code translates the point (0, 0) relative to the respective control to coordinates relative to the containing StackPanel, and hence gives the position of each control inside the StackPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the position of a control is determined by the control which holds it, the margin property, the alignement and such.

You could use this to determine the position of the child control.